# SMPS Transformer Area of Product

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, magnetics

I've calculated the area of product needed for transformer, it's 71cm^4, but in core datasheets there is not value with cm^4 unit for example: https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/db/fer/e_65_32_27.pdf, 
am I missing something here? How can I choose a core for calculated area of product in cm^4
[image]

https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup126/slup126.pdf

Comment: I know very little about this topic but why would area be measured in    \$ cm^4 \$? I don't think you're missing something - I think you've got something extra.

Comment: source added to question

Comment: The source mentions on page 8 the **area product** which is different to the "area of product" in your question.

Comment: This is a way to determine the power handled by a specific transformer core. The *area product* is the product of the core window area by the cross-sectional area. As both are expressed in \$cm^2\$ you have \$cm^4\$ at the end. This is a classic to design power transformers. Some manufacturers do include these data in their data-sheets (look at [Magnetics](https://www.mag-inc.com/getattachment/Products/Ferrite-Cores/Learn-More-about-Ferrite-Cores/Magnetics-Ferrite-Catalog-2017.pdf?lang=en-US) for instance) but some not and you have to resort to a core listing giving this AP parameter.

Answer (score 7):

Now that we've got the formula and source reference we can see that the source mentions on page 8 the **area product** which is different to the "area of product" in your question. (If you want an "of" in there it would be the "product of areas" rather than the other way around.)

> Core Selection: Size
>
> A novice in the art of transformer design usually
> needs some guidance in making an initial estimate of
> the core size appropriate for the application requirements. One widely used method, with many variations, is based on the core Area Product, obtained by
> multiplying the core magnetic cross-section area by
> the window area available for the winding.

Just before the AP equation the article explains ...

> Some core manufacturers no longer provide area
> product information on their data sheets, often substituting their own methodology to make an initial
> core size choice for various applications.

That means that you'd have to calculate it from the information given in a datasheet.

---

[image]

Going back to the datasheet we can see that the area of the centre core, *A<sub>E</sub>* is 20 × 27.4 = 540 mm<sup>2</sup> = 5.4 cm<sup>2</sup>.

<s>I don't know whether the winding window is in the same orientation or at right angles so I'll assume that it's in the same plane as *A<sub>E</sub>*. From the drawing we can calculate that the window area, *A<sub>W</sub>* = 12 × 27.4 = 324 mm<sup>2</sup> = 3.24 cm<sup>2</sup>.</s>

A<sub>W</sub> (often referred to as A<sub>N</sub> in datasheets) is the area that is filled by the cross sections of the wires:

[image]

A<sub>W</sub> = (22.2 × 2) × (12) = 533mm² = 5.33cm².

Since some of this area is occupied by the bobbin (a.k.a. coil former), it's always lower than calculated. That's why this area is given in the datasheets for various types of bobbins for the same core. As can be seen at p.4 in the datasheet, A<sub>W</sub> is given as **4.35cm²** for the only bobbin. As stated above, winding window area is mostly given as **A<sub>N</sub>** in datasheets.

From those numbers we can calculate:

*AP = A<sub>E</sub> × A<sub>W</sub>* = <s>5.4 × 3.24 = 17.5 cm<sup>4</sup></s> 5.4 × 4.35 = 23.5cm<sup>4</sup>

<s>Remember that I don't know what I'm talking about.</s>

Comment: Aw is determined by the coil former. Because there's always a dead/unused zone for winding. So it's not the correct way to directly multiply the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for that. The article says that, "*This formula is based on current density of
420 A/cm² in the windings, and assumes a window
utilization of 40% copper.*" Would that make any difference to your comment?

Comment: I meant the way of the calculation of Aw in your answer. You multiplied the dimensions directly but it's not the way. I hope I could describe with my terrible English and understood what you said correctly.

Comment: Can you correct my misunderstanding in your answer or by an add-on edit to mine? Your English is excellent in all your posts and better than many native writers here.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. I've put the info about Aw in your answer here as this is more detailed than mine.

Answer (score 4):

As @Transistor stated, it's the **Area Product**, not **Area of Product**.

The value can be used to select a core for required power level.

It's the product of core's central area which is given as **A<sub>E</sub>**, and the winding window area which is given as **A<sub>N</sub>** (aka A<sub>W</sub>). Please note that, unlike how @Transistor has shown in his answer, the value of **A<sub>N</sub> is determined entirely by the bobbin** (i.e. coil former).

> How can I choose a core for calculated area of product in cm^4

Today manufacturers publish a list of cores for various power ranges and topologies. But still the AP method is useful. If you have the value of AP and not have a list for cores/power levels then pick a core, find its A<sub>E</sub> and A<sub>N</sub> (or A<sub>W</sub>) from the datasheet and multiply them. If the result is larger than or equal to your required value then the core is suitable for your needs.

For example, let's check if E65 is suitable for you: A<sub>E</sub>=530mm²=5.3cm² and A<sub>N</sub>=4.35cm². AP=23.06cm⁴ which is much lower than your needs. So it's not suitable.

PS: I'd like to know which values are you used for AP calculation. 71cm⁴ is quite large to me.

Comment: I got 2kW power at output, so there is more than 2kW on transformer because of rectifier and filter losses so I took it as 2.5kW power (worst scenario), than K constant is 0.017 for bridge converters, I choose 200mT as deltaB(100 positive and 100 negative), and 30kHz for transformer operating frequency.